# queueing array of promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an array of promises having about 10000 indexes. I need to resolve them all. but as i try to resolve them via `Promise.all` just like

```
const arrayOfPromises = [];
for(let i=0;i<10000;i++){
  arrayOfPromises.push(asyncFunction(i));
}
await Promise.all(
  await Promise.map(arrayOfPromises, res => {
    console.log(res);
  }),
);
```

it gives error `connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:3000`. But same code is working fine with 500 promises.

I want a solution to resolve this array in efficient way without any error.

Comment: There's also [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) and [promise-queue](https://github.com/promise-queue/promise-queue) if you're interested in using a package instead of rolling your own.

Comment: If you already have an array of promises, it's too late. You already called the function that starts the async work ten thousand times.

Comment: @Bergi I am building this array just before this code.

Comment: @Bergi what solution will you suggest for it. Should i not build the array ? or what should i do while pushing promises into the array ?

Comment: @AhmadRaza the easy solution is bluebird's `Promise.map`. If you could [edit] your question to include the code that builds the array, I can post an answer.